# How to get nested grouping for List with mapped values with Java 8 streams

Tags: java, java-8, grouping, java-stream

I have a List and need convert it to nested (2 levels) map, where list is grouped by 2 different object properties and values should use third properties. Example:

```
[A("1","2","3"),A("1","2","4"),A("1","3","4"),A("2","3","5")]
```

should be converted to

```
{1={2=[3, 4], 3=[4]}, 2={3=[5]}}
```

Now to get this result I use the following construction:

```
    Map<String,Map<String,List<A>>> grouppedRecords = list.stream().collect(groupingBy(A::getA, groupingBy(A::getB)));

    Map<String,Map<String,List<String>>> results =  grouppedRecords.entrySet().stream().collect(Collectors.toMap(
            Map.Entry::getKey,
            e12 -> e12.getValue().entrySet().stream().collect(Collectors.toMap(
                    Map.Entry::getKey,
                    e22 -> e22.getValue().stream().map(A::getC).collect(Collectors.toList())
            )))
    );
```

But it looks over-complicated. Could you help me with a better way to sove the same problem?

Comment: According to your description, don't you rather want `{(1, 2) = [3, 4], (1, 3) = [4], (2, 3) = [5]}`?

Comment: No, meant nested mapping

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `Collectors.mapping` to map the `A` instances to `getC()`:

```
Map<String,Map<String,List<String>>> results = 
    list.stream()
        .collect(groupingBy(A::getA, 
                            groupingBy(A::getB,
                                       mapping(A::getC, toList()))));
```

Comment: Thank you. That's what I looked for.